# WinForms DataGridView Question

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

**Situation**
I have 3 Interface defined as follows.

```
public interface IA { long ID { get; set; } }

public interface IB : IA { string Name { get; set; } }

public interface IC : IB { string City { get; set; } }
```

Then I have a class called `SampleClass` that implements `IC` and in that class, I have a method called `GetData()` which returns `List<IC>`.

Then in my Windows Form, I have a `DataGridView`. I am binding the grid as follows.

```
SampleClass sampleClass = new SampleClass();
List<IC> list = new List<IC>();

foreach (var item in sampleClass.GetData())
{
    list.Add(((C)item));   
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

**Question**
The Grid displays only the fields from Interface `IC` and none of the fields from interface `IB` or `IA` shows up. Any idea why?

Comment: Update your tags to include what language, looks like C# but...

Comment: To those answering, I believe his question is *WHY* don't the methods of IB and IA show up, not *HOW DO I* make the methods show up.  In other words, since IC inherits IB and IA, shouldn't IC have IB and IA methods?

Answer (score 0):

The datasource is binded to a list of IC, the grid display IC data. If you bind your grid the the concrete class that inherit IC, you will be able to see IB too.